# Apache rewrite rule matching one condition but not matching another

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite everything that does not start with wp-content but ends in .html. My failed attempt:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html /$1-pages/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Remove rewrite condition and change rewrite rule to `RewriteRule ^/?(?!wp-content/)(.*)\.html$ /$1-pages/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: That works @revo. Would you like to make it an anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `RewriteCond` here. Just modify next rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(?!wp-content/)(.*)\.html$ /$1-pages/ [R=301,L]
```

I used a negative lookahead to negate the results.